# "Root" key from plist is not recognized from the AppDelegate?

Tags: objective-c, plist

i have a simple question : why does "origineArray" return (null) ? i found out that if i put all the code in the RootViewController it works, but if i put it in the AppDelegate (as it is in a sample code, i don't which way is better?) , it does not recognize the "Root" key :

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self){
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
        NSString *finalPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"origine.plist"];
        origine = [[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:finalPath]retain];
    }
    return self;
}


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
    NSLog(@"origine data : %@", origine);
    NSArray *origineArray = [origine objectForKey:@"Root"];
    NSLog(@"origineArray data : %@", origineArray);
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application delegate is created in a nib file, the `init` method is not called. Items in nibs are archived already initialized.

If you want initialization of an object loaded from a NIB, implement the `- (void) awakeFromNib` method.

Comment: thanks, i've got my code in the AppDelegate actually, can you start off your app with a plist file "from" a nib? so created from the Interface Builder?

Comment: I don't believe there's a way to create a NSDictionary from a plist file and have it wired up automatically in interface builder. However, if you put your loading code in the awakeFromNib method of your delegate rather than your init, it should load appropriately.

Comment: Thanks, ok actually i had to put "NSArray" instead of "NSDictionary", since the "Root" is an array, i did not see that mistake at first. Thanks anyway for your help !

Answer (score 0):

You are logging the "origine" dictionary, what does it log to the console? If the "Root" key is not there then you are not opening the right file obviously. If the dictionary is NULL then you need to fix the path.

Are you sure that **finalPath** contains the right path? It seems that the origin.plist is in the resources folder but you are using the location of your app bundle in the finder.